# UIScrollView's Frame getting changed randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitableview

In my view I am using a UITableView that is controlled by a UITableViewController on the top half of the screen. The remaining screen is used for a UIScrollView that contains a view that is controlled by the main UIViewController.

When I perform a pull down to refresh in the UITableViewController, (for some reason if the number of table entries is less than or greater than the initial load value, the UIScrollView in the main UIViewController's frame gets changed to the screensize...

Essentially it breaks my paging unless I reset the scrollview back to the intialized size...

I have no idea why this happens as the UIScrollView is not used in the UITableViewController. The only scrollview that is used in the UITableViewController is the UITableView's to handle pull down to refresh...

Does anyone know why the main UIScrollView's contentSize gets changed randomly when it shouldn't even been accessible from the UITableViewController class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it here, and I can't duplicate your experience. I'm guessing you have an unexpected or inconsistent view/controller hierarchy? Look at the controller of the table and scroll views' common superview. Anything fishy there? Remember: view controllers manage sets of *views*. Container view controllers manage other *view controllers* and have special rules (see: [The View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), esp. `-addChildViewController:`, etc.).

I'd suggest opening a blank project and trying to recreate the problem in its simplest possible form. If it's magically fixed, what's different? If it's still giving you trouble, send us a link so we can see the details of how you have things wired.

Comment: I am guessing this could be a problem. I did not do anything special to the containerView that manages these controllers besides initializing the instance variable of the Viewcontroller in my project. What else do I need to do to have it setup properly? I now just added addChildViewController, but it had no effect.

Comment: Read the section "Creating Custom Container View Controllers" in the above-linked documentation to get started. You might also want to watch WWDC 2011 Session 102 "Implementing UIViewController Containment". But this doesn't feel like a simple bug -- there are probably a few subtle things wrong. So I'd still suggest making a new "simplest possible" implementation (maybe with all three views managed by the single root view controller?) just to make sure this is reproducible and caused by what you think it is.